# How can I find out the exact conditions when STL containers throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, stl

For STL containers (so far, `std::vector<>` and `std::deque<>`), I'm looking for documentation that says exactly when they throw exceptions. Something like, "It throws X in situation A. It throws Y in situation B. It throws no other exceptions under any circumstances."

I'd like to reassure my exception-phobic colleagues that we know exactly what can trigger exceptions in the STL classes we use.

Comment: In general though, the standard containers and algorithms are pretty conservative when it comes to exceptions.  If you have plenty of memory, and don't access indexes out of bounds, you pretty much won't encounter them.  Most exceptions coming from containers actually came from the elements in the containers.

Comment: Pretty much the only exception that can be thrown by a container itself is when calling `at`, any other exceptions will be thrown by the allocator or the contained type.

Comment: The containers themselves do not throw often, but the problem is that the objects that are stored inside may throw, for example a copy constructor can throw, then you may end up with containers left in a non-specified state. The book of Josuttis http://www.cppstdlib.com/ is a great reference that covers basically everything you need to know.

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but any time you invoke undefined behavior, you may very well get an exception, even if the spec does not say that you will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most accurate information will come from the C++ standard matching your compiler, and compiler documentation.  However, the spec costs money.  If you're willing to settle for a few typos, the draft C++11 specification can be found here: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf for free, and the latest publicly available draft (preparing for C++14) seems to be http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf.

The number 1 used container is `vector`, so lets go over that.

Technically the only `vector` member that throws an exception is `at`, if given an out of range index. (tada! we're done!)

Less technically, `vector` assign/insert/emplace/reserve/resize/push_back/emplace_back/shrink_to_fit/etc can cause a resize, which uses `std::allocator<T>:allocate`, which can throw `std::bad_alloc` in theory.  In weird situations with weird allocators, swap can also trigger this too.  On some systems (Linux), this pretty much never happens, because it only throws if it runs out of *virtual* memory, and often the program will run out of *physical* memory first, and the OS will simply kill the whole program.  That happens regardless of exceptions though, so this doesn't count against C++ exceptions.

Probably relevant is that the elements *in* a vector can throw any exception when copied, which affects constructors, assignment, insert/emplace/push_back/emplace_back, reserve, resize/shrink_to_fit. (If your element has a `noexcept` move constructor and move assignment, and it really really really should, then happens only when copying the entire vector).

The spec details exactly what exceptions are thrown and often also specifies under exactly what conditions they're thrown.

Comment: This is pretty much correct, but the latest available draft of the C++14 standard is n3936. Search for it. Behaviour on failed memory allocation is implementation-defined.

Comment: § 20.7.9.1/7 of C++11 draft says "`Throws: bad_alloc if the storage cannot be obtained.`". All links to n3936 are dead, it seems to be removed, latest public seems to be n3797

Comment: I have a copy and there is one here: https://github.com/zygoloid/cplusplus/blob/master/papers/N3936.pdf. I agree STL allocators will never throw any other exception but (as you say) an implementation may not throw any at all.

Comment: @david.pfx: Such a thing would be only standards conforming if allocation could never fail

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard documents when exceptions will be thrown and under what circumstances for the standard library containers. There are also general rules about which methods will not throw exceptions for containers.

Alternatively, you can search the headers for throw (or the equivalent macro) to determine under what circumstances exceptions will trigger.